# php oil r install is giving Fatal error and not able to install FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

I am installing FuelPHP on Windows 10 but getting Fatal error while running "php composer.phar install" command and not able to install it. The error I am getting is given below:

```
     php composer.phar install --verbose
     Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Nothing to install or update
    Generating autoload files

    Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in D:\projects\campaygn\src\fuel\core\classes\error.php on line 146

    Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in D:\projects\campaygn\src\fuel\core\bootstrap.php on line 47
    Script php oil r install handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



      [RuntimeException]
      Error Output:



     Exception trace:
     () at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:186
     Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:121
     Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchCommandEvent() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:337
     Composer\Installer->run() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:131
     Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
     Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
     Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
     Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
     Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://D:/projects/campaygn/src/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
     require() at D:\projects\campaygn\src\composer.phar:25


    install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: As extra information, I have already tried this thing with newest version of composer.phar file :)

Comment: No help came, not even from the Forum of FuelPHP.

Comment: You never responded to the questions you were asked about what you installed, how you installed it, and where you got it from.

Comment: I had more than 1 composer files in my system; so solved it by installing the other one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

this error might come when you have more than 1 composer.phar file in your project folder.
Have a thorough look in your folder and update and install all composer. Specially src/fuel/app :p

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help a lot, but [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/instructions.html) it says:

> Command Line Installation
>   This currently only works on *nix systems (Linux, OS X, Unix, etc).

Comment: Providing php.exe is available in the path, the installation should work on Windows as well. The "oil" installer is a bash script, and doesn't work on Windows, but that is not the problem here. The error is that the oil commandline processor can't load a core class, which can only be caused by either a missing file, a permission issue, or non-standard installation in combination with incorrect configuration. As the TS said on the forum he downloaded "something" from Bitbucket, and FuelPHP isn't on bitbucket, no answer can be given unless we have more details.